# Hinge joint is not firm, leaving connected anchor position

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody, hinge-joint

I have a hook with hinge joint which is working fine but as my object quickly move my hook leave its position for a while.

[image]

And here is the hinge joint settings with rigidbody:

[image]

[Here](https://twitter.com/voiceoffaizan/status/1045619147797942272) is a short clip of the problem.

Comment: How are you moving the object atm?

Comment: Object is crane which is moving through animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent object which was moving the Hook working through animation and by setting its animator update mode to **[AnimatePhysics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation-animatePhysics.html)**, the problme has resolved. What Animate Physics property do is:

> **When turned on**, animations will be executed in the **physics loop**. This
>   is only useful in conjunction with kinematic rigidbodies.
>
> An animated platform can apply velocity and friction to rigid bodies
>   sitting on top of it. In order to use this, animatePhysics must be
>   enabled and animated object must be a kinematic rigid body.

Now the animation is executing in same physics loop which has resolved the issue.

*Thanks to [Chance Millar](https://twitter.com/ValeourM/status/1045645927975985157).*

Answer (score 1):

It may depend if you're using animation for move parent object.

If you move the object using it's transform this could not happen.

Comment: Yes You maybe right.!! I have found the answer.